# TryUpdateModel fails only in unit tests to update child objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, nunit

I am able to get the following code to work on the server, but not in a unit test. In the unit test, the simple properties are set correctly, but the child objects are not. I've been beating my head against the wall for too long, so any advice would be welcome.

#### Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Save(int id)
{
        var itemFromRepository = this.itemRepository.FetchById(id);

        if (itemFromRepository != null)
        {
            this.TryUpdateModel(
                itemFromRepository,
                "Item",
                new[] { 
                    "AnIntProperty", 
                    "AStringProperty",
                    "Category.Id"
                });

            if (itemFromRepository.Category!= null)
            {
                itemFromRepository.Category= this.categoryRepository.FetchById(itemFromRepository.Category.Id);
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                this.itemRepository.Update(itemFromRepository);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
}
```

#### UnitTest:

```
    this._controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext();
    Item item = this.items.First();
    var updatedCategory = this.categories.Last();
    var updatedStringProperty = "Fake Value";
    var updatedIntProperty = 4;

    var formValues = new FormCollection {
        { "Item.AnIntProperty", updatedStringProperty},
        { "Item.Category.Id", updatedCategory.Id.ToString() },
        { "Item.AStringProperty", updatedIntProperty.ToString() }
    };

    var result = this._controller
        .WithIncomingValues(formValues)
        .Save(item.Id);
```

This passes:

```
    Assert.That(
        item.AStringProperty,
        Is.EqualTo(updatedStringProperty));
    Assert.That(
        item.AnIntProperty,
        Is.EqualTo(updatedIntProperty));
```

This doesn't:

```
    Assert.That(
        item.Category,
        Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(
        item.Category.Name,
        Is.EqualTo(updatedCategory.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see that the previous category is not null?  In the following code you only update the value if it is not null, you can get a null value for category in two cases. 1. If the value is currently null and 2. possibly if your categoryRepository.FetchById returns a null reference.

```
if (itemFromRepository.Category!= null)
{
     itemFromRepository.Category= this.categoryRepository.FetchById(itemFromRepository.Category.Id);
}
```

Both of these situations would cause your assert to fail.